# Inequality between norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: analysis

I am trying to show that $\lVert x\rVert_q\leq\lVert x\rVert_p\leq\lVert x\rVert_1$ for $1<p<q$ where $\lVert x\rVert_p=(\sum |x_i|^p)^{1/p}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. This seems like it should be easy to show but I'm somehow having trouble. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $(a+b)^r \leq a^r +b^r$ for any $0<r<1$ and non-negative $a,b$.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dumb but how can we show the hint is true?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse

Answer (score 0):

Recall that for any norm, $\|cx\|=c\|x\|$ when $c>0$. So we may assume without loss of generality that $\|x\|_p = 1$. Then $|x_i|\leqslant 1$ for each $i$, so
$$\|x\|_q^q = \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^q\leqslant\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p=1. $$
Raising both sides to the $\frac1q$ we obtain
$$\|x\|_q\leqslant \|x\|_p. $$
The inequality $\|x\|_p\leqslant \|x\|_1$ follows by a similar argument.